# Button automatically click?

Tags: java, android

I need to have a button automatically click. Either on the creation of the activity, or on a timer that I will set to a very short time. Can anyone help me out with this. How do I call for the button to be clicked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call the `OnClickListener` (if any) using [performClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29).

Comment: Some thing like this?

((Button) findViewById(R.id.imap)).performClick();

Comment: There's no need to typecast to a `Button`, that method is defined on the `View` super class.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to on Click automatic .
Please call ButtonName.performClick();
NOTE : you must Setonclick for that Button

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling onClick() method of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the code of your button in `OnCreate()` and change the button background so it looks like `clickable` when your activity start..

Answer (score 0):

you can use inbuild method of button `buttonName.callOnClick()`

Answer (score -1):

```
yourbutton.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 mybutton.performClick();
            }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

work for me
please use this

> button.callOnClick();