# How to auto click button when video is available in android?

Tags: android

I have Integrated some rewarded video ads in my app an activity which contain a Button named as `Show Video` when I click on that I navigated to video activity which show video adds ,but problem is that Video takes time to view,I want to show a progress dialog and when `Videovisibilty` becomes "true" then hide progress dialog and auto click button to show video.

How can I do that ?

mainActivity code:-

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        _button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_button);
        _button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Video.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }
```

Video activity code:-

```
 String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Supersonic mMediationAgent;
    private Placement mPlacement;
    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Loading video :) ");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.show();

        mMediationAgent = SupersonicFactory.getInstance();
        // Supersonic Advertiser SDK call
        SupersonicAdsAdvertiserAgent.getInstance().reportAppStarted(Video.this);
        mMediationAgent.setRewardedVideoListener(Video.this);
        final String userId = "9555515291";
        final String appKey = "50427d";
        mMediationAgent.initRewardedVideo(Video.this, appKey, userId);
        IntegrationHelper.validateIntegration(Video.this);
        if (mMediationAgent.isRewardedVideoAvailable()) {
            mMediationAgent.showRewardedVideo("DefaultRewardedVideo");
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoInitSuccess() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRewardedVideoInitSuccess");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoInitFail(SupersonicError supersonicError) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        // called when the video is closed
        Log.d(TAG, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed");

        // here we show a dialog to the user if he was rewarded
        if (mPlacement != null) {
            // if the user was rewarded
            showRewardDialog(mPlacement);
            mPlacement = null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoAvailabilityChanged(boolean b) {
        // called when the video availbility has changed
        Log.d(TAG, "onVideoAvailabilityChanged" + " " + b);

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStart() {
        // called when the video has started
        Log.d(TAG, "onVideoStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnd() {
        // called when the video has ended
        Log.d(TAG, "onVideoEnd");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdRewarded(Placement placement) {
        // called when the video has been rewarded and a reward can be given to the user
        Log.d(TAG, "onRewardedVideoAdRewarded" + " " + placement);
        mPlacement = placement;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoShowFail(SupersonicError supersonicError) {
        // called when the video has failed to show
        // you can get the error data by accessing the supersonicError object
        // supersonicError.getErrorCode();
        // supersonicError.getErrorMessage();
        Log.d(TAG, "onRewardedVideoShowFail" + " " + supersonicError);
    }

    public void showRewardDialog(Placement placement) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Video.this);
        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.rewarded_dialog_header));
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.rewarded_dialog_message) + " " + placement.getRewardAmount() + " " + placement.getRewardName());
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If my answer helps then kindly accept it, so other users can get benefit of this.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `performClick()` like

```
 btnViewVideo.performClick();
```

When you use this at that point any action write in the onclick listner will be fired automatically.

For more info:
[fire button's click event programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628599/button-automatically-click)

Comment: If this helps then kindly accept it, so other users can get benefit of this.